# Why would spatial join return correct distances but wrong attributes

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.2, spatial-join

I am doing spatial joins on points and street (line) features to identify the closest street to each point. However, despite getting appropriate distances returned for each points, closest road, the attributes of the identified road, in some cases an incorrect road and it seems to be one road specifically that is favoured. Projections of both layers and the project are consistent and nothing is selected in either layer. Am I missing anything?

Attached image shows features joined with same identified attribute for street, but distances, which are more appropriate to the points highlighted.

[image]

And the parameters for join...

[image]

---

Just to clear this up - the dataset I was using had been modified by others adding in extra features, which seems to have introduced my problem. I'm not sure why or how exactly, but going back to the original set with no extra features returns the results I would expect.

Comment: A screenshot of your spat. join parameters may be helpful.

Comment: Actually, I meant the settings that you chose to perform the join.

Comment: Extremely long name for shapefile is sometimes / always bad idea. Try 8 symbols long

Comment: Have you tried running Repair Geometry on your street or point files? Whenever I run in to weird spatial bugs, I run a repair and try again. I suspect it might be the road layer that needs to be repaired.

Comment: Looks like there is a duplication of results in the highlighted rows. Assuming your in OSGB36 using ITN data. Is High precision on in the geodatabase?

Comment: Thanks for responses. Will try the repair and am also going to try in QGIS to see if I get the same or different result. Duplication of results is the odd bit - the join is identifying correct distances to nearest feature but reporting attributes of others - largely one single one. i.e. it is not entirely duplicated or throughout the set and the distances are not based on the distance to the feature the attributes have been taken from.